# Svelte: style particular element without a globally unique name

Tags: css, svelte

What css selector could I use below to target just the outer div?

```html
<div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>

<style>
    OUTER.DIV.ONLY {
        background: url(outer.png);
    }
</style>
```

Alternatively, I'd be happy to know if there is a way to name the outer div with a *locally scoped* name that doesn't add anything to the compiled svelte.

I can't just add `class="outer"` because that is way too likely to conflict with existing stylesheets.

I could add `class="outer-au9a8bo9u"` but that's clunky, especially since that class will add useless bytes to the svelte compiler output.

I'm posting this in the hopes that there's something more elegant and efficient than that.

Comment: Stephane's answer would seem to address your need but I don't see why you can't use a class. In svelte all css in a component is scoped unless you declare it as global so there would be no conflict.

Comment: Svelte scopes the contents of the <style> to protect other components from your styles, but it does not scope your html's class="..." to protect your component from global CSS. If I add class="outer" then the rendered output will contain class="outer"... Which is both a waste of space and can cause unintended styling from global CSS that I don't know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with CSS:

```css
div:not(div > div)
```

Literally 'a div that is not the child of another div'. Not exactly the prettiest selector every, but it works.

**update**

It seems the above does not always work due to (what I suspect) a bug where the selectors inside the not are not scoped. ([bug report](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6545)

As an alternative you can turn the logic around:

```css
/* adds background everywhere */
div {
  background-image: url(...);
}
/* remove again from children */
div div {
  background-image: unset;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you :) It's not the ugliest either, especially if it's sitting right next to a "div > div" selector for the inner divs.

Comment: oy, this selector doesn't work in svelte because svelte doesn't scope the part inside the not()

Comment: hmm, that feels like a bug, I filed one here https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6545 it seems that in the mean time you will have to resort to the use of classes or reverse the logic (edited my answer to reflect this)

Comment: Agreed! I spent some time looking at the svelte source code. It doesn't appear to consider selectors that are arguments to pseudo-classes. Also while I was investigating that I found a related bug where it's breaking some pseudo-classes that appear at the beginning of the line (including :global()) https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6550